# NtCreateFile - can't seem to read a file that exists

Tags: windows, ntdll

I am attempting to read ntdl.dll from disk using NTCreateFile, but it does not seem to be reading the file properly. The native call does not return a valid handle. Could someone who is more familiar with this native call point out what is wrong with this code? Thanks!

```
FORCEINLINE VOID RtlInitUnicodeString(
    _Out_ PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString,
    _In_opt_ PWSTR SourceString
)
{
    if (SourceString)
        DestinationString->MaximumLength = (DestinationString->Length = (USHORT)(wcslen(SourceString) * sizeof(WCHAR))) + sizeof(WCHAR);
    else
        DestinationString->MaximumLength = DestinationString->Length = 0;

    DestinationString->Buffer = SourceString;
}

#define OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE 0x00000040
#define FILE_OPEN 0x00000001 
#define     FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE   0x00000001

#define InitializeObjectAttributes(p, n, a, r, s) { \
(p)->Length = sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES); \
(p)->RootDirectory = r; \
(p)->Attributes = a; \
(p)->ObjectName = n; \
(p)->SecurityDescriptor = s; \
(p)->SecurityQualityOfService = NULL; \
}

HANDLE file = NULL;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
UNICODE_STRING f;
UNICODE_STRING fp;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;

WCHAR ntdl[100] = L"\\??\\\\C:\\windows\\system32\\ntdll.dll";
RtlInitUnicodeString(&f, ntdl);
RtlInitUnicodeString(&fp, filepath);

InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, &f, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

NtCreateFile(&file, FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &IoStatusBlock, 0, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_OPEN, FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Why can't you just use CreateFile? Are you sure Ntdll supports that path?

Comment: I am trying to avoid userland calls if possible. CreateFile is just a wrapper for NtCreateFile, so it should work by calling the native call directly.

Comment: Avoid them because? Call CreateFile and set a breakpoint on NtCreateFile and compare parameters, Windows vs you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Path needs to be `L"\\??\\C:\\windows\\system32\\ntdll.dll"`
- `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`, not `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE`.

Comment: Yeah this was actually the reason, I also realized that this morning. Now I am having fun trying to figure out why readfile and ntreadfile isn't working lol. Fml.